# jquery autonumeric plugin: want to get null from blank fields, but it gets auto-filled with zeros

Tags: jquery-plugins

The "autoNumeric" plugin fills the input fields with zeros as soon as the field got focused or even hovered over. I want to let end user leave some fields blank. Blank is not the same as zero. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the documentation for the `emptyInputBehavior` option in the `AutoNumericOptions.js` file:

```
/* Defines what should be displayed in the element if the raw value is an empty string ('').
 * - 'focus'  : The currency sign is displayed when the input receives focus (default)
 * - 'press'  : The currency sign is displayed whenever a key is being pressed
 * - 'always' : The currency sign is always displayed
 * - 'zero'   : A zero is displayed ('rounded' with or without a currency sign) if the input has no value on focus out
 * - 'null'   : When the element is empty, the `rawValue` and the element value/text is set to `null`. This also allows to set the value to `null` using `anElement.set(null)`.
 */
emptyInputBehavior: {
    null  : 'null',
    focus : 'focus',
    press : 'press',
    always: 'always',
    zero  : 'zero',
},
```

What you want is to set `emptyInputBehavior` to `'focus'` (which is the default), and you won't get any 'zero' added to your input.
This is with the version `v4` in `next`.

Answer (score 2):

In my usecase, setting the `emptyInputBehavior` to `'null'` worked:

```
emptyInputBehavior: 'null'
```

That way, when the input field is emptied, its value is set to `null`.